# ImageMagick 'no decode delegate for this image format' for jpeg but works when reading in jpegs

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, jpeg, imagick

I'm working with ImageMagick and am really confused at the error:

> 'no decode delegate for this image format

My research has led me to understand that this might be caused by not having specific packages installed for jpegs. However I'm confused because I can `readImage` on jpegs, but when I try to composite them, I cannot. Is this what this error is saying?

For example:

```
$img->readImage(image.jpg);
header ('Content-Type: image/jpg');
echo $img;
```

The result of this is a simple image outlaid on the page. No problems here.

Then, I try to do the following:

```
$fiveRow = new Imagick();
$fiveRow->newImage($width * 5 + $padding * 3 , $height, 'white');
$fiveRow->setImageFormat('png');
$fiveRow->compositeImage($img, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, $left + $offset, 0);
```

And then I try to output the composite:

```
header ('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $fiveRow;
```

And I get the `no decode delegate` error again. But why? JPEG is supported and it's obviously fine outputting a jpeg on the page, why as soon as I composite it does ImageMagick 'magically' no longer have this package?

When running `phpinfo()` I can see that JPEG is a supported format in the massive list:

> 3FR, A, AAI, AI, ART, ARW, AVI, AVS, B, BGR, BGRA, BMP, BMP2, BMP3,
>   BRF, C, CAL, CALS, CANVAS, CAPTION, CIN, CIP, CLIP, CMYK, CMYKA, CR2,
>   CRW, CUR, CUT, DCM, DCR, DCX, DDS, DFONT, DNG, DPX, DXT1, DXT5, EPDF,
>   EPI, EPS, EPS2, EPS3, EPSF, EPSI, EPT, EPT2, EPT3, ERF, FAX, FITS,
>   FRACTAL, FTS, G, G3, GIF, GIF87, GRADIENT, GRAY, GROUP4, HALD, HDR,
>   HISTOGRAM, HRZ, HTM, HTML, ICB, ICO, ICON, INFO, INLINE, IPL, ISOBRL,
>   JNG, JNX, JPEG, JPG, JSON, K, K25, KDC, LABEL, M, M2V, M4V, MAC, MAP,
>   MASK, MAT, MATTE, MEF, MIFF, MNG, MONO, MOV, MP4, MPC, MPEG, MPG, MRW,
>   MSL, MSVG, MTV, MVG, NEF, NRW, NULL, O, ORF, OTB, OTF, PAL, PALM, PAM,
>   PANGO, PATTERN, PBM, PCD, PCDS, PCL, PCT, PCX, PDB, PDF, PDFA, PEF,
>   PES, PFA, PFB, PFM, PGM, PICON, PICT, PIX, PJPEG, PLASMA, PNG, PNG00,
>   PNG24, PNG32, PNG48, PNG64, PNG8, PNM, PPM, PREVIEW, PS, PS2, PS3,
>   PSB, PSD, PTIF, PWP, R, RADIAL-GRADIENT, RAF, RAS, RAW, RGB, RGBA,
>   RGBO, RGF, RLA, RLE, RMF, RW2, SCR, SCREENSHOT, SCT, SFW, SGI, SHTML,
>   SPARSE-COLOR, SR2, SRF, STEGANO, SUN, SVG, SVGZ, TEXT, TGA, THUMBNAIL,
>   TIFF, TIFF64, TILE, TIM, TTC, TTF, TXT, UBRL, UIL, UYVY, VDA, VICAR,
>   VID, VIFF, VIPS, VST, WBMP, WMV, WPG, X3F, XBM, XC, XCF, XPM, XPS, XV,
>   Y, YCbCr, YCbCrA, YUV

Comment: If you issue `convert -list configure | grep DELEGATES`, are `jpeg` and `jp2` included in the list? Maybe you need to install libjasper/libopenjp2/jp2-delegate as add-on?

Comment: @TomRegner Just jpeg, not jp2: `DELEGATES      bzlib mpeg freetype jng jpeg lcms lzma png ps tiff xml zlib`

Comment: Is one of the images perchance a jpeg2000 image? Then you would need the jp2 delegate

Comment: @TomRegner they are all standard jpeg. I have resaved them just to check. They are 100% just standard jpeg. Also, I can read them in, why can't I composite them? Why is this error only showing up now even though reading and writing just the file is fine?

Comment: Did you try to write it as `jpeg`, not `png`? Does `$fiveRow->writeImage('filename.png');` work?

Comment: @TomRegner I've tried changing it to PNG. I've tried changing the files themselves to PNG. I've tried reading in the JPG, saving it as PNG, reading the new PNG in and compositing that. None of this works. Nothing can be composited. This code was working fine this morning. No changes.

Comment: Strange -- in that case I would `strace` the process to see what's going on in terms of opened libs (.so), files etc.

Comment: You are probably mixing and matching the versions of Imagick and ImageMagick. This in not supported. You can only use a compile Imagick with the version of ImageMagick it was compiled against.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you find something out?